# magento 2 admin showing error but no message

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, production-mode

I have recently switched my magento 2.4.3-p1 instance to production mode but now it is showing an error in admin panel but with no text. No js error in console no error in log files.
Do anyone have any idea? attaching the picture
[image]

Answer (score 0):

please run this command
php bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0